# Phonegap Local Notification not working

Tags: cordova-plugins, phonegap, localnotification

I am trying to use this plugin to setup scheduled notifications. But it doesn't works at all.
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

I have installed plugin both through npm and cli(for 0.9-beta version).
I am copying same code from repository only.
Calling it after deviceready event.

But nothing works.